# here is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ado.net

protected void cmdLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    Class1.con = CreateConnection();
    string str = "SELECT Ad_Regid from Admin_Profile WHERE Ad_Regid LIKE @TempPasscode";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(str, Class1.con);
    if(Class1.con.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
        Class1.con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempPasscode", txtcurrentpwd.Text.Trim());
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr[0].ToString() == txtcurrentpwd.Text)
        {
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand("_insertAdminLogin", Class1.con))
                if (Class1.con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                Class1.con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdminType", ddltype.SelectedItem.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdminUsrname", txtuname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdminPwd", txtconfirmpwd.Text);

                **using cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**
         }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Warning", "javascript:alert('Temporary Password Does not Match!');", true);
            }
         }
        Class1.con.Close();
}
```

I am trying to save 3 fields but it showing there is one open data reader "you should close it"...but i use the using keyword for the same use....

Help please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling cmd.ExecunoteNonQuery, call `dr.Close();`